Helm template issue with range
I have the following code which includes two templates
{{- $tests:= list "foo" "bar" }}  
    {{- range $test := $tests}}  
    {{- $context := dict "Test" $test "Values" $.Values "Global" $ }}  
    {{- include "template.works" $context | nindent 4 }}  
    {{- include "template.does.not-work" $context | nindent 4 }}  
    {{- end }}  

and the templates are
{{- define "template.works" -}}  
- name: name-{{ .test}}  
{{- end}}  

and
{{- define "template.does.not-work" -}}  
{{- range $i, $deploy := .Values.deployments }}  
- name: name-{{ $deploy.revision }}-{{ .test}}  
{{- end}  
{{- end}

the template.works is fine the test value is populated.
But it is not populated in template.does.not-work .
The problem is related to the range. If I removed it everything is fine.
What am I doing wrong here?
Does the range overwrites the values that I defined in the context? And how can I address that?

. inside a defined helper refers to the parameter you pass to it when you include (or template) to invoke it, so it only contains what is in $context in the caller.
